# How can I disallow lenient dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I'm trying to validate if a string is a valid date. `Date.parse(dateString)` or `new Date(dateString)` both are very lenient. For example a date like `14/14/2000` is coming out as `2/14/2001`. I tried a regular expression but now I'm needing to validate more than `mm/dd/yyyy`, I also need to validate `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss` e.g. `1951-02-05T00:00:00`.

I was using regular expressions and some basic date checks right now, but the second date format above is failing the regex.

```
function isDate(dateToCheck) {
    if (dateToCheck == "" || dateToCheck == null) { return true; }
    var timestamp = Date.parse(dateToCheck);
    var d = new Date(timestamp);
    var re = /(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d/;

    var valid = re.test(dateToCheck);
    valid = valid && !isNaN(timestamp);
    valid = valid && d.getFullYear() > 1900 && d.getFullYear() < 2100;
    return valid;
}
```

The regex is specifically for `mm/dd/yyyy` where month and day are both double digits (single digit months get a leading zero) and won't allow invalid months or days like 14 as a month or 32 as a day. The year can be anything from 1900 to 2099.

It's not air tight. It would allow 02/31/2000 which is invalid because February never has 31 days.

How can I validate both of these date formats without allowing lenient dates?

Comment: `Date.parse('14/14/2000')` returns `NaN` - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bic742/hk6Aa/1/). Date.parse returns an integer conversion of the date you provide it. If it is `NaN`, the date is invalid. `new Data('14/14/2000')` returns `Invalid Date`.

Comment: @Bic `Date.parse('14/14/2000')` in IE10 returns `982134000000`. I cannot trust it for an internal website that will only run on IE10.

Comment: Fair enough. Leave it to IE to do things differently and make life hard.

Comment: @Bic At least I don't have to worry about cross browser fixes...

Comment: I added a full example of my response. If it works for you please select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both can be validated with this.

```
 #  /^(?:(?:(?:19|20)\d\d[- \/.](?:0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})|(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](?:19|20)\d{2}))$/

 ^ 
 (?:
      (?:
           (?: 19 | 20 )
           \d\d [- /.] 
           (?: 0 [1-9] | 1 [012] )
           [- /.] 
           (?: 0 [1-9] | [12] [0-9] | 3 [01] )
           T \d{2} : \d{2} : \d{2} 
      )
   |  (?:
           (?: 0 [1-9] | 1 [012] )
           [- /.] 
           (?: 0 [1-9] | [12] [0-9] | 3 [01] )
           [- /.] 
           (?: 19 | 20 )
           \d{2} 
      )
 )
 $
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at moment.js, and all their parsing options.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Their is an isValid() function that you can use to validate if the input string was correct.

```
moment("not a real date").isValid(); // false
```

If you combing that with a date validation string then you get the result you are looking for:
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/

```
var m = moment('14/14/2000', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
console.log(m.toString(),m.isValid());
//"Not a valid date"
//false
```

**Update:** I made a [test harness on JS-Bin with your full sample data.](http://jsbin.com/qiwas/latest/) Here is the full working example code using Moment.js. You can specify multiple formats for to try before it will return `isValid()`.

```
function momentIsDate (dateToCheck) {
  return moment(dateToCheck, [
    'DD/MM/YYYY',
    'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'
  ]).isValid();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use the "lenient date" functionality against itself in a pretty cool way to handle this issue.  Starting out by using your `mm/dd/yyyy` example, first make sure that the value matches that format, then, if it does, use the value to create a new `Date` object:

```
var checkDateVal = new Date(dateToCheck);
```

Then, using that new value, rebuild the date string:

```
var checkDateMonth = checkDateVal.getDate();
var checkDateDay = checkDateVal.getMonth() + 1;
var checkDateYear = checkDateVal.getFullYear();

// force two digits for the day and month, if necessary
checkDateMonth = (checkDateMonth < 10) ? "0" + checkDateMonth : checkDateMonth;
checkDateDay = (checkDateDay < 10) ? "0" + checkDateDay : checkDateDay;

var checkDateString = checkDateMonth + "/" + checkDateDay + "/" + checkDateYear;
```

Now compare the original date input to the new string value that you created:

```
if (dateToCheck !== checkDateString) {
    // Yell at user for bad data
}
```

If the date string that was input by the user does not match the date string that was created by the `Date` object, that means that the object was forced to "massage" the input value to create a real date . . . which means that original input value was an invalid date value to begin with.

And there is your check.   :)

The same logic can be applied to the longer date format that you mention . . . I'd recommend using two regex values at the beginning to determine which format the original input is in, and then use that as a flag to drive logic downstream (e.g., how the `checkDateString` needs to be built to see if the input was valid).

Comment: This gets complicated when different formats might come in. I'd have to know how exactly to rebuild the date into a string.

Comment: You are going to need to know that in order to apply to appropriate format checks in regex as well.  Really, though, the only thing that changes though is how you rebuild the string . . . the rest of the logic is common.  But, then again, even with plugins, things will get more complex with each new format that you support.  I've written a lot of data validations over the years and, believe it or not, this is the quickest "vanilla JS" way that I've found to check for invalid date values that are correctly formatted.